# Developer -> Product Owner - what skills should focus on in order to make the job transition?

Tags: product-owner

In order to change career from a developer to product owner, what do you think should be the focus on.

The developer is a technical person and should make a transition to a customer oriented person/business oriented person.

What recommendations do you have?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The ex-developer must resist the urge to develop :-)

If they continue to develop code, they are likely interfering with the product developers, possibly tend to micromanage, and above all keep their head stuffed with development thoughts while they should be communicating with the various party and structuring the insights gained.

Apart from that, as Nezih Tinas noted, deep knowledge of the product is an invaluable advantage, as it allows the PO to communicate with the devs on the same level, and make informed contributions to the decision-making process.

Comment: Definitely agree with that - a coding product owner would most probably produce mediocre code and poor management

Answer (score 0):

The "Customers" of product owners are the "Product Managers". The "Product Managers" define the product according to many aspects like market conditions, customer expectations, regulations, etc.

What the "Product Owner" should do are;

1. Knowing the product from A to Z
2. Thinking like a developer to close the gaps in the workflows/use cases
3. Translating the workflows/use cases to technical terminology and incorporating them into the current product

So, if you are good at closing gaps and telling another developer what to do, then it means that you are a good candidate for a Product Owner.